# Is there a way to only accept a file with a certain name for an input button?

Tags: html, file, input

The `accept` object property filters files with a certain extension -- but is there a way to filter based on object name as well?

```
<input type="file" id="HelloWorld" accept=".txt"></input>
```

Let's say I wanted to filter for a file called "HelloWorld" with the extension of ".txt". How could this be done?

Comment: I don't think you can do that natively. Instead you could use, `JS` to check for name and throw an error instead. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-accept

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you only can provide mime types according this page: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-accept

> **accept**
>
> If the value of the type attribute is file, then this attribute will
>   indicate the types of files that the server accepts, otherwise it will
>   be ignored. The value must be a comma-separated list of unique content
>   type specifiers: A file extension starting with the STOP character
>   (U+002E). (e.g. .jpg, .png, .doc).
>
> A valid MIME type with no extensions.
>
> - audio/* representing sound files.
> - video/* representing video
> - files. HTML5 image/* representing image files.

To explicit check the filename you need to do something with javascript or in your backend where you POST.

Answer (score 0):

The "accept" argument only filters on file types and extensions (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/file)

You could write a JavaScript handler on before form post, or server-side handler, to capture and validate that the correct file name was chosen -- in fact, if you truly needed the file type to be correct, you would want to do this anyway -- as noted in the above reference documentation:

> The accept attribute doesn't validate the types of the selected files; it simply provides hints for browsers to guide users towards selecting the correct file types. It is still possible (in most cases) for users to toggle an option in the file chooser that makes it possible to override this and select any file they wish, and then choose incorrect file types.
>
> Because of this, you should make sure that the accept attribute is backed up by appropriate server-side validation.